# ¿Cómo guardo atributos estáticos en un fichero?

Tags: java, poo, archivo, static

Me gustaría saber por qué al guardar objetos en un fichero y cargarlos de nuevo los atributos estáticos no se me cargan y en su lugar valen 0 (El método que da valores a los atributos estáticos está en otra clase y durante la ejecución tienen esos valores pero al guardarlos y cargarlos no).
Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
    public class Coche extends Vehículo implements Serializable {
        private String color;
        private static int ruedas;
}
```

Este es el método que utilizo para guardar los objetos en el fichero:

```
public void guardarVehiculos() {
        String file = "ConfigFiles/Vehiculos.txt";
            try {
                ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                for (int i=0;i<this.vehiculos.size();i++) {
                    output.writeObject(this.vehiculos.get(i));
                }
                output.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                File f = new File("ConfigFiles/Vehiculos.txt");
                try {
                    f.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
    }
```

Este es el método que utilizo para cargarlos del fichero:

```
private void cargarVehiculos() {
        this.vehiculos = new ArrayList<>();
        String file = "ConfigFiles/Vehiculos.txt";
        boolean obj = true;
        try {
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            while (obj) {
                Vehiculo vehiculo = (Vehiculo) input.readObject();
                if (vehiculo != null) {
                    this.vehiculos.add(vehiculo);
                }
                else
                    obj = false;
        

}

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        File f = new File("ConfigFiles/Vehiculo.txt");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    }
    if (this.vehiculos.size() == 0) {
        this.crearVehiculos();
        this.guardarVehiculos();
    }

}

public void crearVehiculos(){
    Coche coche = new Coche("Azul");
    Coche coche2 = new Coche("Verde");
    this.vehiculos.append(coche);
    this.vehiculos.append(coche2);
    coche.setRuedas(4);
    Moto moto = new Moto("negro");
    this.vehiculos.append(moto);
    moto.setRuedas(2);
}

public void setRuedas(int ruedas){
    Coche.ruedas = ruedas;
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Jorge, supongo que en el método **crearVehiculos** (que no subiste) instancias objetos **Coche**, me gustaría verlo, por otro lado en **guardarVehiculos** me parece que deberías cambiar **output.writeObject( this.vehiculos.get(i) );** crear dentro del for,lo que necesitas guardar y al salir de este, escribir en el archivo.

Comment: Ya añadí los métodos. La cosa es que tengo otro método que también utiliza el setRuedas y al imprimir por consola me sale que las cambia correctamente pero al guardar los objetos como que no se me guardan y al cargarlos estas valen 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comenzar, debes recordar que los atributos estáticos no pertenecen a cada instancia del objeto, sino a la clase en si, y no parece tener mucho sentido escribir estos a un archivo.

Por esta misma razón, las rutinas estándar de serialización/deserialización los ignoran, de la documentación de [ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object)):

> Write the specified object to the ObjectOutputStream. The class of the object, the signature of the class, and the values of the **non-transient and non-static** fields of the class and all of its supertypes are written

Mi traducción libre:

> Escribe el objeto especificado al ObjectOutputStream. La clase del objeto, la firma de la clase y los valores de los campos **no transitorios y no estáticos** de la clase y sus ancestros son escritos.

Dicho esto, puedes *personalizar* completamente la escritura de un objeto Serializable escribiendo los métodos `writeObject` y `readObject` en tu clase `Coche`.

Para lograrlo, puedes también valerte de los métodos [`defaultWriteObject()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#defaultWriteObject()) y [defaultReadObject()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#defaultReadObject()) para mantener la escritura y lectura *estándar* que escribe y lee los atributos de la instancia y, sobre esto, escribir el valor que te interesa, por ejemplo:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Coche extends Vehículo implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String color;
    private static int ruedas;

    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
            throws IOException {
        stream.defaultWriteObject();
        stream.writeInt(ruedas);
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        stream.defaultReadObject();
        ruedas = stream.readInt();
    }
}
```

Como he dicho antes, no tiene mucho sentido escribir un valor estático para cada instancia dentro del stream.

Dado el ejemplo, sospecho que nos encontramos ante una instancia del [problema XY], pues las clases `Coche` y `Moto` podrían fácilmente incluir el valor del atributo `ruedas` en la declaración, así:

```
public class Coche extends Vehículo implements Serializable {
    private String color;
    private static int ruedas = 4;
}
```

Y ya con eso, no hace falta serializar el valor que, igual está *quemado* en el código, solo que, a mi manera de ver, en un lugar poco apropiado.